# how to do DFT on different functions in time and frequency domain?

Tags: matlab

I am beginner at FFT and i am trying to learn FFT very well IN MATLAB. but i have problem with concept of FFT and difference of time and frequency domain.
I have 2 questions and i will be grateful if someone help me to learn them.

1- DFT can be implemented both in time and frequency domain??? what is the difference between sampling in time and frequency domain???

2- I want to do DFT on Step function ( t=45 seconds and sampling interval in time domain was given 0.01 s) anyone can help me how to write this code in MATLAB ????

Thanks,

Comment: ??? The DFT transforms a time domain signal into its frequency domain representation.  I don't understand how you can implement the DFT "in frequency domain"... that's a catch 22.

Answer (score 0):

1.A DFT is a transistion from time domain to frequency domain and and IDFT does the opposite (f->t).
Sampling in time means you look at the signal in time intervals (e.g. 0,001s).
In frequency domain it tells you how much frequency is between each value. The last value in frequency domain is the inverse of the sample time (in the example above 1000Hz). So if you do a DFT with 1000 samples you get a spacing of 1Hz.

2. Just instert 45s/0.01s samples into the DFT. Make sure that you get exactly one period of the function, else you get window leakage.

Comment: good job. for example in my case, during 45 second with 0.01 s  time interval i will have 4500 samples and then i can do DFT on it. in frequency domain it says, between each sample there is 100 Hz frequency and if i have 4500 sample i will get a spacing of 45 Hz . is it correct???????

Comment: Sorry for the late reply: Sounds correct to me. Keep in mind that the time and the frequency domain are believed to be periodic (because the other is discrete). So everything you feed into it is believed to be a exact period of a periodical sequence. If not you get effects like window leakage. You can also read the 2nd half part of the spectrum as -50 to 0Hz because of the periodicity and you should do so because of the shannon-nyquist theorem. If I my answer is what you needed please mark it as that.